# Why does Spring Autowire fail when I move @SpringBootApplication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm completely new to Spring/Spring Boot so I need some help. I didn't notice any documentation that indicated that the `@SpringBootApplication` or `@ComponentScan` had to be in a particular spot:

**Working folder structures**

[image: Working folder structure]

[image: Working folder structure 2]

**Not working**

[image: Not working folder structure]

Comment: If you don't specify a scanning base package it will start scanning from the package containing the annotated application class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your `Application` class is a typical Spring Boot Application like following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`SpringBootApplication` is just a composed annotation of:

```
// Others
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public @interface SpringBootApplication { .. }
```

That `ComponentScan` with no explicit base package, would use the package of `Application` class as its base package for scanning. So, when you put this class in your root package, any annotated class in root package and under it would be scanned by the component scanner and your app would successfully work.

But when you move your `Application` into `app` package, that very same component scanner wouldn't scan those beans in `hello` package and Spring would fail to wire some beans together.

Spring Boot does not require any specific code layout to work, however, there are some best practices that help. You can read about those best practices in [Spring Boot Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was just using @SpringBootApplication. I didn't know that it was just a shortcut for the other annotations, but that makes sense. Thanks!